# How do I get $\mathbb{E}[h(X)g(Y)] = \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[g(Y)\mid X]h(X)]$?

Tags: probability

How do I get $\mathbb{E}[h(X)g(Y)] = \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[g(Y)\mid X]h(X)]$?

---

I know that $$\mathbb{E}[h(X)] = \int_X h(x)f(x) \; dx$$ and $$\mathbb{E}[h(X,Y)] = \int_{X\times Y}g(x,y)f(x,y) \; dy \; dx$$

But then $\mathbb{E}[g(X)h(Y)]$ is?

Answer (score 1):

$$
\mathbb E(h(X) g(Y)\mid X) = h(X)\cdot\mathbb E(g(Y)\mid X)
$$
because when one conditions on the value of $X$, anything whose value is determined by $X$ becomes in effect a "constant".  Its value is constant on every subset of the probability space on which $X$ has a particular value.

One the original probability space, the expression on both sides of the equality above is a random variable and is a function of $X$.

Now take expected values of both sides of the equality above and you've got it.

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{aligned}
\int_X \int_Y h(x)g(y) f(x,y) \; dy \; dx
&= \int_X \int_Y h(x)g(y) f(y\mid x)f(x) \; dy \; dx \\
&= \int_X \left(\int_Y g(y) f(y\mid x) \; dy \right) \; h(x) f(x) \; dx \\
&= \int_X \mathbb{E}[g(Y)\mid X] \; h(x)f(x) \; dx \\
&= \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[g(Y)\mid X] h(X)]
\end{aligned}$$